# What are the advantages, disadvantages and example use cases of the different PowerShell module / script types?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, powershell, memory-management

At the time of this post there are a number different PowerShell module / script types as listed on the [offical MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.

The page lists [Script Modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Binary Modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Manifest Modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and Dynamic Modules.

Although, each of the pages listed above go into detail about how to create said module, none of the pages list any details about when to consider using a certain module type or the advantages and disadvantages of each.

For example (just an example), if one builds a script module that relies heavily on PowerShell 4 cmdlets and attempts to run it in a PowerShell 2 environment, the module that was created would not run. However, if one were to create a PowerShell module using C#, they would be able to run their cmdlet on any version of Windows as long as the underlying .NET framework matched the required framework of the module that was written at a cost of system memory used at script load time.

These script details are not listed on the MSDN pages, and I have not been able to find any useful information about these differences on the internet or the books I have read.

**What are the advantages and use cases of the different module types above?**

Comment: Depending on a specific version of .Net being installed for C# is about as reliable as depending on a specific version of PowerShell being installed. Also, the answer to this could be a few chapters in a book.

Comment: Note that it's not a "Manifest Module", it's a "Module Manifest", which is merely data describing the contents of a module. Hence the term *manifest*.

Comment: @mikez I agree with you, but look at how it's documented on the official MSDN page. The first link in the post above.

Comment: @DodziDzakuma Interesting. In a sense they are very similar, any module can have a manifest, but if a module consists solely of a manifest then it is called a "manifest module". The link provided is actually describing module manifests, not manifest modules.

Comment: @BoogaRoo To simplify the question just a little bit, what situations should I use pure PowerShell to make cmdlets and what situations would it be recommended to use C# to make cmdlets? I may change the question to fit this a bit more, but with that wording it might become more opinion based.